# How to Close React App on Electron App Quit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have a Electron + React app that is working on port 3000. When I call the app.quit method from Electron's start.js file, it exits from the Electron but I can still see that 0.0.0.0:3000 is in LISTENING state from netstat -ao.

I am working on Windows 10 and I tried app.exit(0) from electron file, however React app is still reachable from Browser and netstat -ao shows 0.0.0.0:3000 in LISTENING state.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nf start -p 3000",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-start": "node src/start-react",
    "react-start": "SET BROWSER=none&&react-scripts start",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "npm run build && build",
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g foreman"
  },
```

I want to close ReactApp completely after/before calling app.quit() of Electron
Here is the code I use for closing app.

```
ipcMain.on('closeApp', (evt, arg) => {
    app.exit(0)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the `0.0.0.0:3000` still listening because you didn't close the connection properly. You need to close the react app server before quit the app. There is an event named `before-quit` in electron `app` triggered exactly before app quits. You can utilize the callback to close server. To look up the `pid` attached to port 3000, There is a [find-process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-process) package, after finding the `pid`, kill the process. Consider the given example.

```js
const find = require('find-process');

app.on('before-quit' , (e) => {
    find('port', 3000)
      .then(function (list) {
      if(list[0] != null){
          process.kill(list[0].pid, 'SIGHUP');
      }
    }.catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.stack || e);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Then may I ask what is the code block to close ReactJS completely and gracefully. I couldn't find anything rather then killing the PID that is running on Reacts port.

Comment: That's the way, you have to find out the process attached to port 3000 (here you are attaching the react server to port 3000 so it always be the process of yours) and kill that process before quitting the app.